# Is compile-time "strlen()" effective?

Tags: c++, string, templates, performance

Sometimes it is necessary to compare a string's length with a constant.
For example:

```
if ( line.length() > 2 )
{
    // Do something...
}
```

But I am trying to avoid using "magic" constants in code.
Usually I use such code:

```
if ( line.length() > strlen("[]") )
{
    // Do something...
}
```

It is more readable, but not efficient because of the function call.
I wrote template functions as follow:

```
template<size_t N>
size_t _lenof(const char (&)[N])
{
    return N - 1;
}

template<size_t N>
size_t _lenof(const wchar_t (&)[N])
{
    return N - 1;
}

// Using:
if ( line.length() > _lenof("[]") )
{
    // Do something...
}
```

In a release build (VisualStudio 2008) it produces pretty good code:

```
cmp    dword ptr [esp+27Ch],2 
jbe    011D7FA5
```

And the good thing is that the compiler doesn't include the "[]" string in the binary output.

Is it a compiler specific optimisation or is it a common behavior?

Comment: you could probably use one template for all array types, something lie this: `template<class T, size_t N> size_t _lenof(const T (&)[N]) { return N - 1; }`, should still work the same as your example.

Comment: @Evan Teran: good idea, but these functions make sense only for strings (array of char/wchar_t) because of terminating '\0'. Your function will work for int[10] and return 9 - I don't think that it make sense ;)

Comment: @Evan Teran: N == 0? How? even _lenof("") N == 1. The function return 0 - it's correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your title question. Did you mean *compile-time*? And what do you mean by "effective"?

Comment: @Dmitriy: you are right I was over thinking it, deleting that second comment.

Comment: I think there is a pretty good chance that gcc's machinery takes care of that. I mean, if it cares about eliminating `sin(1)`, then dammit please also for `strlen("foo")` :)

Comment: @litb: But it's not true for VisualStudio...

Comment: What optimization level are you using? Can that influence the results? (Just out of curiosity, I have not used VS for a long time (4 years)

Comment: Now you can use `constexpr` :)

Comment: FWIW, this template trick is also described in Scott Meyers's "Effective Modern C++" (2014).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capability to inline a function call is both a compiler-specific optimization *and* a common behavior. That is, many compilers can do it, but they aren't required to.

Comment: The desired optimisation doesn't (just) require inlining. It requires that the length of the string be computed at compile time.

Comment: That's not really an optimization, though. The length wouldn't be computed at run time and still call any `_lenof` function. Doesn't the standard *require* implementations to give string literals the type `const char[N]`? And aren't values of such type required to make the compiler deduce the arguments of the template function to be `N`?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what your answer was referring to - for some reason I though you were talking about "not efficient because of [the strlen] function call". If a compiler can't inline _lenof, then it probably can't inline anything, and would be a pretty poor C++ compiler in general. Any serious use of templates would be nightmarish...

Answer (score 14):

Why not

```
sizeof "[]" - 1;
```

(minus one for the trailing null.  You could
do sizeof "[]" - sizeof '\0', but sizeof '\0'
is often sizeof( int ) in C, and "- 1 " is
perfectly readable.)

Comment: could be fixed for wide strings. Something like: `(sizeof(L"[]") / sizeof(L"")) - 1`

Comment: @Evan Teran: yes, but you should use macros to make it more readable. IMHO macros it's more C style but not C++

Comment: I agree, was just pointing out that this technique was usable for wide strings. I was not endorsing it :-P.

Answer (score 3):

I think most compilers will optimize it away *when optimizations are enabled*. If they're disabled, it might slow your program down much more than necessary.

I would prefer your template functions, as they're guaranteed to not call `strlen` at runtime.
Of course, rather than writing separate functions for `char` and `wchar_t`, you could add another template argument, and get a function which works for any type:

```
template <typename Char_t, int len>
int static_strlen(const Char_t (&)[N] array){
  return len / sizeof(Char_t) - 1;
}
```

(As already mentioned in comments, this will give funny results if passed an array of ints, but are you likely to do that? It's meant for strings, after all)

A final note, the name `_strlen` is *bad*. All name at namespace scope beginning with an underscore are reserved to the implementation. You risk some nasty naming conflicts.

By the way, why is "[]" less of a magic constant than 2 is?

In both cases, it is a literal that has to be changed if the format of the string it is compared to changes.

Comment: For whatever reason, your function doesn't appear to be faster than using strlen. However, it does appear to be faster than using std::char_traits<Char_t>::length, so it's still useful as strlen only works on char arrays.

Comment: Pretty sure that the compiler can't optimize it away.  That would be very dangerous.  You are making a function call.  Yes, it is to a common function, but the compiler can not be sure of that.  If you didn't link against a standard libc, you could link with a custom function of the same name.  All the computer knows is that it is calling a function called strlen with a parameter of type char*.  It can't know what that function does, so it can't optimize it away.

Answer (score -12):

```
#define TWO 2
#define STRING_LENGTH 2
/* ... etc ... */
```

Seriously, why go through all this hassle just to avoid typing a 2?  I honestly think you're making your code less readable, and other programmers are going to stare at you like you're snorting the used coffee from the filter.

Comment: it's just example. In real code it looks like "some string". Are you going to count number of characters in this case? :)

Comment: Yes, I am. And I will. And I do.

Comment: @Jed Smith: :) Are you sure that you don't forget to change the macro definition if the string changes?

Comment: @Jed Smith: How is "2" more readable/understandable then sizeof("[]") ?

Comment: @Jed: Hey, if it's only a 2, then why bother? When it's "some string I might change and I don't want to bother eyeballing the length of" it's a different story. OTOH, strlen() is only a problem when it's really a problem. Assuming it's a problem is a form of guessing.