# Efficient passing of string literals in C++

Tags: c++, string, templates

While writing code for wrapping Lua, I came across the need for passing string literals and started to wonder which way it is the most efficient.

I have the choice between two functions:

1. `void lua_pushstring (lua_State* L, const char* str);`
2. `void lua_pushlstring(lua_State* L, const char* str, size_t len);`

Of course, the 1st function uses `strlen()` internally, the 2nd one is thus faster.

Now, if it's known at compile time, I'd like to avoid calculating string length, as laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391708/is-compile-time-strlen-effective) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173743/why-isnt-string-assignment-optimised-when-the-length-is-known-to-the-compiler):

```
// Overload 1
template <size_t N>
inline void pushstring(lua_State* L, const char (&str) [N])
{
    lua_pushlstring(L, str, N-1);
}
```

As nice as this function works when called with a string literal: `pushstring(L, "test");` of course it doesn't compile when called with a `const char*`, for example in a longer function which is in a `.cpp` file:

```
// this is in a .cpp file
void long_function(lua_State* L, const char* str)
{
    // do lots of stuff
    pushstring(L, str);  // compile error
    // do more stuff
}
```

Now if I add

```
// Overload 2
inline void pushstring(lua_State* L, const char* str)
{
    lua_pushstring(L, str);
}
```

it is for some reason (C++ overload resolution is tricky) preferred over `Overload 1`, which is thus never called.

Is there a clever way to fix that?

Comment: I tried something in analogy to yours: http://ideone.com/Tb4mq Maybe this gives you inspiration.

Comment: @Nobody: That should be the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate further on your template version:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
inline void pushstring(T str);

template <int N>
inline void pushstring(const char (&str) [N])
{
   std::cout << N << std::endl;
}

template <>
inline void pushstring(const char *str)
{
   std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

See a test run here:
Wrong parameter -> linker error: http://ideone.com/vZbj6 
Rigt parameter -> runs great :) : http://ideone.com/iJBAo

Comment: Tadaa! Nice. Just template it and it works. Any idea why in this case the overloading rules are different?

Comment: I guess the template specialization gets only triggered on demand after there was no overloaded version found. As the direct overload matches no template is used. But this is (as already said) only a guess.

Comment: @marton78: Templates allow no conversion on the type arguments, which means that once overload determines that the appropriate overload is the base template, it deduces `T` to be the type of the argument. That is where overload resolution ends and template instantiation begins. At this point `T` is either `const char*` or `const char [N]` but no conversions are allowed, and the proper specialization (not *overload*) is instantiated

Comment: But what if other code relies on implicit conversions to const char*, e.g. via operator T? I couldn't get this to work in real-world codebase trying different variants.
Bonus question, maybe related: What if there's another overload with std::string as parameter?

Answer (score 4):

If you declare *both* with the second one forwarding to the first:

```
void lua_pushlstring(lua_State* L, const char* str, size_t len);

inline void lua_pushstring (lua_State* L, const char* str)
{ lua_pushlstring(L, str, strlen(str)); }
```

Then a decent compiler will optimise away the `strlen` call when you call the second function with a literal, e.g. it will inline

```
lua_pushstring(L, "hello");
```

and because `strlen` on a literal can be optimised to a constant, it will replace it with a call to:

```
lua_pushlstring(L, "hello", 5);
```

That gives you the simple syntax of calling the two-argument form, without paying for `strlen` on literals.

When the length is already known it can be passed:

```
lua_pushlstring(L, s.c_str(), s.length());
```

Or this works too, but with an unnecessary call to `strlen`

```
lua_pushstring(L, s.c_str());
```

Comment: Re: "strlen on a literal can be optimised to a constant" -- Really? I've never heard of that. Can you provide a source that confirms that, maybe even with a list of compilers that support this optimization and under which circumstances?

Comment: At least GCC and Clang do it, see http://preview.tinyurl.com/cy3jnnt for the assembly output proving it (look for `movl $5, %edx`). If other compilers don't support it then stop using them.

Comment: In summary, K.I.S.S. and let the compiler do its job.

Comment: Nice. I always thought this would be a nice optimization but didn't know it's actually performed.

Answer (score 4):

I would offer two options:

```
void f( const char*, int );
template <int N> void f( const char (&str)[N] ) {
   f( str, N-1 );
}
```

(or rather `std::size_t`), Now users that have a string literal can call the second that will internally dispatch to the first. Users that don't have a literal but a `const char*` are responsible for providing the correct size.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too, but that's rather clumsy, isn't it?

Comment: @marton78: These are your only options. The `void f(const char (&str)[N])` will only be chosen with a string literal or known array as the argument, never when something that's only known as a const char* is passed, as seen in `long_function`.

Comment: @marton78: I have used this in the past, and I don't find it clumsy. It is basically the `(ptr,size)` function and a helper that allows user code not to calculate the size if the string is a literal --while picking up potential mistakes at compile time.

Comment: In the end, I used a combination of your and Nobody's answer: I have Nobody's templates calling your `void f(const char*, size_t);
`

Comment: @marton78: In performance critical code (most code isn't, this probably does not affect you) it is important knowing the *cost* of the operations. In that case, providing the three flavors has the negative impact that user code does not know whether `strlen` is called. Consider that the call was `f( str.c_str() )`, the templated overload for `const char*` will be picked up, and it will call `strlen` while user code already knew that the size is `str.size()`. The extra sugar coating is negatively impacting your program. I'd rather let the user known whether an expensive operation might be done.

Comment: ... that is, your *abstraction* has an impact in performance. The alternative is having the user call `strlen` if needed on their side, or providing the size if it is already known (as in the example above)

Comment: All right, I see what you mean and I agree. In performance critical code `f(const char*)` should be disallowed. Btw, "first" and "second" are mixed up in your answer. I will do as you suggest, however, the Nobody answered the part on overload resolution, so I'll leave his answer checked, if that's ok.

Comment: @marton78: Thanks for picking up the first/second thing. I swapped the order when I provided the implementation of the template and missed updating the text. Regarding the tick, I don't need any more rep :)